# Difference between Enum and Objects with 'string' key and 'number' value pair

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, enums

What is the difference between an enum object and a regular object with 'string' keys and 'number' values ?

```
// THIS  IS TYPESCRIPT CODE

enum Role { ADMIN, READ_ONLY_USER, FINANCES } // enum

const Role_alt = { ADMIN : 0, READ_ONLY_USER : 1, FINANCES : 2 } // object with 'string' keys and 'number' values

console.log(Role.FINANCES) // <- 2
console.log(Role_alt.FINANCES) // <- 2
```

It gets transpiled to this JS:

```
var Role;                                                   // 
(function (Role) {                                          //        
    Role[(Role["ADMIN"] = 0)] = "ADMIN";                    // object declared as enum in TS
    Role[(Role["READ_ONLY_USER"] = 1)] = "READ_ONLY_USER";  //
    Role[(Role["FINANCES"] = 2)] = "FINANCES";              //
})(Role || (Role = {}));                                    //

var Role_alt = { ADMIN: 0, READ_ONLY_USER: 1, FINANCES: 2 }; // object with 'string' keys and 'number' values

console.log(Role.FINANCES); // <- 2
console.log(Role_alt.FINANCES); // <- 2
```

Obviously, the enum is transpiled to much complex code. I was wondering what the advantage of that is.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum Role { ADMIN, READ_ONLY_USER, FINANCES } // enum

const Role_alt = { ADMIN : 0, READ_ONLY_USER : 1, FINANCES : 2 } // object with 'string' keys and 'number' values

console.log(Role.FINANCES) // <- 2
console.log(Role_alt.FINANCES) // <- 2
```

Well, because you can also do this, and you can't with a normal object:

```
Role[2] // "FINANCES"
```

Sometimes it is useful, sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference

Here's the example

```
enum Value {
  No = 0,
  Yes = 1,
}
function demo(response: Value): void {
  //
}
```

But if it was const

```
const ValueConst {
  No: 0,
  Yes: 1,
}
function demo(response: typeof ValueConst): void {
  // have to use `typeof`, otherwise you get an Error
  // 'ValueConst' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ValueConst'?
}
```

And also enums are readonly

```
ValueConst.No = 1 // enables assignment (Not good)
Value.No = 1 // Cannot assign to 'No' because it is a read-only property.
```

And from [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)

> The biggest argument in favour of this format over TypeScript’s enum
> is that it keeps your codebase aligned with the state of JavaScript,
> and [when/if](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-enum) enums are added to JavaScript then you can move to the
> additional syntax.

Answer (score 0):

An enum generally has a string value and a numeric value that relates to that string value.

In TS, you can parse `1` into `Role.READ_ONLY_USER`, and `'READ_ONLY_USER'` into `Role.READ_ONLY_USER`.
As TS transpiles to JavaScript, the resulting code needs some kind of data format that stores these relations.

The simplest way to do that is to generate an object that contains both:

- The numeric keys with string values;
- The string keys with numeric values.

Then, `Role[1]` will return `'READ_ONLY_USER'`.

So, in short, the numeric keys exist to allow conversion of numbers to enum values.